# Checking inside a column for a particular string ,, android studio

Tags: java, mysql, android-studio, resultset

How do i check for a certain string inside a column.
my sql query would be

> st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Scraped WHERE Category='Hazard'");

and its gonna be viewd by result set, getting all the columns of Scraped with Hazard Category.

now i want to check inside (the data inside a column) one of the column if it contains, for example

> String find = "carrot";

my resultset is like this

```
while (rs.next()) {
            result += rsmd.getColumnName(1)+":"+rs.getString(1) + "\n";
            result += rsmd.getColumnName(2)+":"+rs.getString(2) + "\n";
            result += rsmd.getColumnName(3)+":"+rs.getString(3) + "\n";
            result += rs.getString(4) + "\n";

        }
```

the string i want to check on is on rs.getString(4).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in the SQL using `LIKE`:

```
SELECT * FROM Scraped WHERE Category='Hazard' and col like '%carrot%'
```

if you want to do a case insensitive search, use:

```
SELECT * FROM Scraped WHERE Category='Hazard' and lower(col) like '%carrot%'
```

Comment: this is it,,thanks,, so what im missing is the AND and the wildcard,, thanks a lot! :D

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Scraped WHERE Category like '%carrot%'
```

`%` is a wildcard.